# SAPI echo from delay

Tags: c++, sapi

```
 //All three include files needed for both versions//
#include <sapi.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

//User inputs what is to be said//
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ISpVoice * pVoice = NULL;

    if (FAILED(::CoInitialize(NULL)))
        return FALSE;

    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_SpVoice, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, IID_ISpVoice, (void **)&pVoice);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        std::wstring input;
        while (true)
        {
            std::cout << "Enter text:\n";
            std::getline(std::wcin, input);

            hr = pVoice->Speak(input.c_str(), 0, NULL);
        }
    }
    pVoice->Release();
    pVoice = NULL;
    ::CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

The code is simple. It's microsofts explanation on how to use SAPI with a bit of editing to make the program speak what the user inputs, which I found on this site.

My difficulty has been trying to get an echo effect with the output. From what I've learned, an echo effect is nothing more than playing the same audio at the same time with a minor delay of 10 - 60 milliseconds(respectfully).

With this set up, I can not find a way to play the out at the same time and put a delay variable between the two. The delay part isn't hard, but it's the simultaneous output that I can't figure out.

Comment: Side note: you're reading words, not lines

Comment: Ok that helped. I was able to understand that, by removing the for loop, the output can be done via

`std::cout << "Enter lines of text to speak:\n";`   
`std::wstring text; std::wcin >> text;`   
`hr = pVoice->Speak(text.c_str(), SPF_IS_XML, NULL)`

But making hr play twice at the same time in a way that I can add a delay, still eludes me.

Comment: You'll do much better to apply the echo effect to the audio, not doing the synthesis twice.   For one thing, there's no guarantee that the two engines maintain the same synchronization.

Comment: What should I look at for audio manipulation in C++? Using Visual Studios Express 2013.

Comment: There are a lot of possibilities.  You can do it yourself - [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23745811/adding-echo-effect-to-a-wav-file) shows you how - or you can use a library (search for 'c++ signal processing library' and you'll find dozens to hundreds that will do the trick.